# Running total using two columns

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

Given a table with data like:

| **A** | **B** |
| --- | --- |
| Qty. | Running Total |
| 5 | 5 |
| 5 | 10 |
| 5 | 15 |

I can create the running total using the formula `=SUM($A$2:A2)` and then drag down to get the running total after each quantity (here Qty.)

**What may I do for calculating running total using two columns which may or may not be consecutive** as shown below:

| **A** | **B** | **C** | **D** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Qty. 1 | Other | Qty. 2 | RT |
| 2 | blah | 2 | 4 |
| 2 | phew | 2 | 8 |
| 3 | xyz | 2 | 13 |

Comment: *running total using the formula $A$1:A1*? Did you mean `SUM($A$1:A1)`?

Comment: @JohnSUN Ah yes, thanks. Fixing it.

Comment: OK. Just try `=SUM(A2,C2,E1)`

Comment: @JohnSUN I tried `=SUM(A2,C2,D1)`. It worked brilliantly. Thanks a lot. Would you mind writing an answer with a small explanation? It would be of great help.

Comment: You right - `D1`, not `E1` (my mistake).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place in cell `D2` the formula `=SUM(A2,C2,D1)`. Do not pay attention to the fact that the function will refer to a non-numeric cell `D1` - the `SUM()` function will not break, unlike ordinary addition `=A2+C2+D1`. Now, just stretch the formula down.

Comment: I have just realised that your approach works with one column as well. So, instead of `$A$2:A2`, I could just do the same thing with `A2,B1`. Thanks again!